# How can I prevent a container from being pulled in a docker-compose environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, test-data

I am working with a docker-environment which is used for external testing. The customers depend on the data in the environment so I don't want to pull / up the database container. **Is there an option to have a container in the compose-file but restrain it from being pulled**?

Otherwise I think my way forward is to **remove the container from the compose-file**, which could be bad when someone else will troubleshoot the environment and not all required containers are there.

edit: 
Its around 40 services, so running `docker-compose up <service_name>` is inconvenient and you might miss something.

Comment: Why don't you `up` only the containers that are needed using `docker-compose up service-name`

Comment: time to move k8s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
docker-compose up --scale serviceToExclude=0
```

Where `serviceToExclude` is the container you **DON'T** want to run.

Comment: Won't that hit on all services in the compose-file?

Comment: @beigo this just hit the service(s)(container(s)) you specific after `--scale `, dont affect other services.